# How do you run javascript on included php file/HTML file in-between includes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am including a part of my "master" page as header and a part as footer for uniformity. However, now I want to display a modal on page load on one of the pages. Below is a sample of what I am trying to achieve.

```
<?php
include('header');
?>

<div id="modal"> 

</div> 

<?php
include('footer');
?>

/*
jquery to display modal on pageload. How do you get it to work. Code works 
if the file is not split into includes
*/
<script src="javascript_file">
```

Comment: why dont you have a ; behind the includes?

Comment: @JurickPastechiGenaro `;` is optional if the command is followed by `?>`

Comment: @JurickPastechiGenaro that, actually is not the problem in this case.

Comment: got it fixed. Code works just fine. problem was i was using .load() instead of .on('load', function()...)